# How can I group/associate collections in Meteor JS?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “group by” aggregation queries possible in Meteor, yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266977/are-group-by-aggregation-queries-possible-in-meteor-yet)

I'm attempting to build a list that shows records (projects) in groups (clients). An example would be:

Client A
- Project 1 
- Project 2
- Project 3

Client B
- Project 1
- Project 2
- Project 3

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266977/are-group-by-aggregation-queries-possible-in-meteor-yet